# How to insert csv file to postgresql using jmeter

Tags: sql, postgresql, jmeter

i'm trying to insert CSV data file to POSTGRESQL from JMETER using "LOAD DATA" statement. But LOAD DATA statement won't working. On the internet load statement becoming highlighted and working but on 
my machine its not becoming highlighted and getting error on it.

Here is my SQL query:

"LOAD DATA INFILE '/Desktop/Summary/oca_sum.csv' INTO TABLE Load 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' "

And error is:

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "DATA" Position: 6

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to run a MySQL command against a PostgreSQL database.

PostgreSQL uses a [different syntax](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html) for accomplishing the same task.